# Casper versus Proof of Stake on Other Blockchains

Tags: casper

I get the impression that work on Ethereum's proof of stake protocol Casper is a tough project.

What makes it so that bringing proof of stake to Ethereum is more difficult compared to all the other proof of stake cryptocurrencies that are already out there?